# User enters code into TextBox, code gets added to URL (using session)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session

**I'm using ASP.net 4.0 VB :)**

I am using a session variable to add a user entered code into the url of each page. I can get the code to show up at the end of the page's URL that my textbox is on, but what do I add to every page to make sure that the session stays at the end of every URL that person visits during their session? This is the code from the page that the user enters their user code.

```
  Protected Sub IBTextBoxButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles IBTextBoxButton.Click
  Session("IB") = IBTextBox.Text
  Dim IB As String = Session("IB")
End Sub


 Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
 ProductID.Value = Request.QueryString("id")
 If Session("IB") Is Nothing Then
     tab4.Visible = "False"
 Else
     tab4.Visible = "True"

 End If
End Sub
```

This is what I have in the page load of one of the other pages. What else do I add to make sure that variable is added to the URL of that page?

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim IB As String
    IB = Session("IB")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I threw this code into the Master Page to make sure that every page knows whether or not the Session is there. Thanks for all the help everyone!

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 
Handles Me.Load
  If Session("IB") Is Nothing Then

    IBText.Visible = True
    IBTextBox.Visible = True
    IBTextBoxButton.Visible = True
  Else

    IBText.Visible = False
    IBTextBox.Visible = False
    IBTextBoxButton.Visible = False
    lblIB.Visible = True

    lblIB.Text = "Welcome, " + Session("First_Name") + " " + Session("Last_Name")
  End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  string url = Request.Url.ToString();
  string newUrl = url + url.Contains("?") ? "&" : "?" + "ib=" + Server.UrlEncode(IBTextBox.Text);
  Response.Redirect(newUrl);
  return;
```

Comment: There are squiggly lines under the Response and Return. It says 'declaration expected' - Response and 'Statement cannot appear outside of a method bosy/multiline lambda' - Return

Comment: The code I gave is C# (I haven't looked at VB in years).  And of course that code needs to be within a function. Assuming the user is submitting the page via a button, this code would go in the button's onClick handler.

Comment: I get an error when I enter a code into my textbox that says `Dim newUrl As String = If(url & url.Contains("?"), "&", "?" & "ib=" & Server.UrlEncode(IBTextBox.Text))` 'Input string was not in the correct format.'

Comment: Remember, stackoverflow is an excellent forum for helping get past specific design and coding issues.  It is not intended to be a line-by-line pair-programming or debugging effort - you're going to need to do some of the legwork on your own.  That being said, you might want to augment your original question with some additional code (from the layout and code-behind) to help get past this issue.  It's difficult to help you, based on tiny mini-dumps of partial code with a comment.

Answer (score 1):

The approach I might use would be to create a base page class that all of your pages can inherit.  The base page would then inherit the System.Web.UI.Page.

Within your base page class, create a property for IB and also handle the page load event.

In that event, check if the QueryString has the IB parameter in  it.  If it does, set the property to the value in the parameter.

```
Private _IB As String
Public Property IB() As String
    Get
        Return _IB
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _IB = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Function GetIB(ByVal url As String) As String
    If Not(_IB = String.Empty) Then
        If (url.Contains("?")) Then
            Return "&IB=" & _IB
        Else
            Return url & "?IB=" & _IB
        End If
    Else
        Return url
    End If
End Function

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString("IB"))) Then
        _IB = Request.QueryString("IB")
    End If
End Sub
```

Finally in your markup you would need to place something like the following at the end of all of your links:

```
<a href="<% =GetIB("nextpage.aspx") %>">next page</a>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that there is a database that has all of the codes in it that tie to the products that the IB sells or for us. Would any of that code need to change to tie to that database?

Comment: Yes, you could possibly add a bit of code to check the status of the code in the database.  If it exists then continue with appending it to the URL otherwise drop it.  This could present some overhead problems depending on how busy your site is so using the Cache object might be useful to store the valid codes once retrieved.

Comment: I put that code in the CodeBehind, not sure if that's what you meant but that's how I did it. I used the GetIB in each of the links and when I enter a code in the textbox, nothing happens. The code just sits in the textbox and the page looks like it trys to do something, but it seems to me that it is not doing anything.

Comment: The ?IB= shows up when I click on every link now, how do I make it only show once the user has entered their code?

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  If I am understanding right, I believe the problem of having a blank IB token would be because the _IB variable is empty.  To fix it, wrap the IF block in GetIB with:  
 `If Not (_IB = String.Empty) Then `  Then the block that already exists in this method should be within the block.  I have updated the code above to reflect this.

Comment: Sweet! It doesn't show up anymore. I still need to figure out what to put in the Click event of the button and then I will test to see if this code works with my pages :) Thanks

Comment: Oh whoops, now it is deleting my page names from the end of the URL. I tried to edit the code above but it won't let me, but it should be `Else Return url` instead of `Else Return ""`

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe I did that one on my own haha! My progress is slower than a snail I swear